# JStree is showing the tree in HTML format when supplying different data

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

I have a data, that I supply to JStree in `<ul>` and `<li>`. My Javascript functions are:

```
function displayData(data){
    //your codes to parse and display json data  in html table in your page.
    if (data !=null || data!=undefined){
        var myDiv = document.getElementById("myTree");
        myDiv.innerHTML = data;
        makeTree();
        console.log(data);
    }
    else{
        console.log("No such data!");
    }
}


function makeTree(){
        $('#treeDiv').removeAttr('hidden');
         var tree = $("#myTree");
         $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 500);
            tree.bind("loaded.jstree", function (event, data) {
                tree.jstree("open_all");
            });

        $('#myTree').jstree({

            "plugins": ["checkbox"]
        });

};
```

When I first call the function display data with the data :

```
<ul>
    <li>NodeB
        <ul>
            <li>NodeA
                <ul>
                    <li>NodeC</li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                    <li>NodeD</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I get a JStree like on this picture: [image: JStree view]. 
But when I choose another data and call the display data function again, the data is shown as HTML only. How can I hold the JStree plugin enabled? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you remove the older element of jstree from dom, and create it again it works.

```
        function displayData(data) {
      //your codes to parse and display json data  in html table in your page.
      if (data != null || data != undefined) {
        var myDiv = document.getElementById("myTree");
        var newDiv;
        var parentNode = myDiv.parentNode;
        if (parentNode) {
          parentNode.removeChild(myDiv);
          newDiv = document.createElement('div');
          newDiv.setAttribute('id', 'myTree');
          parentNode.appendChild(newDiv);
        } else {
          newDiv = myDiv;
        }

        newDiv.innerHTML = data;
        makeTree();
        console.log(data);
      } else {
        console.log("No such data!");
      }
    }


    function makeTree() {

      var tree = $("#myTree");
      $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 500);
      tree.bind("loaded.jstree", function(event, data) {
        tree.jstree("open_all");
      });

      $('#myTree').jstree({

        "plugins": ["checkbox"]
      });

    };

    var test1 = '<ul> <li>NodeB <ul> <li>NodeA <ul> <li>NodeC</li> </ul> <ul> <li>NodeD</li> </ul> </li> </ul> </li> </ul>';




    var test2 = '<ul> <li>NodeB-1 <ul> <li>NodeA-2 <ul> <li>NodeC-3</li> </ul> <ul> <li>NodeD-4</li> </ul> </li> </ul> </li> </ul>';

    displayData(test2);

    setTimeout(function() { displayData(test1); }, 4000);
```

I have created a fiddle also :
https://fiddle.jshell.net/brb44wkh/1/

I will check if we have better way of doing it. Hope it helps.